# Background color of a .shp using `readShapeSpatial` function

Tags: r, dictionary, background

I was looking to use a background color on a .shp using `readShapeSpatial` function. Anyone can help me with this?. Is there any function similar (except: `readShapePoly`) that can be used to add a background color to the .shp files?

This is part of my code...

```
library(raster)
library(maptools)
library(mapdata)
library(maps)
library(scales)

pcontorta <- readShapeSpatial("PER_water_areas_dcw.shp")
pcontorta2 <- readShapeSpatial("BOL_water_areas_dcw.shp")
pcontorta3 <- readShapeSpatial("ECU_water_areas_dcw.shp")
pcontorta4 <- readShapeSpatial("PRY_water_areas_dcw.shp")
pcontorta5 <- readShapeSpatial("PER_adm2.shp")
pcontorta6 <- readShapeSpatial("BOL_adm2.shp")
pcontorta7 <- readShapeSpatial("ECU_adm2.shp")
pcontorta8 <- readShapeSpatial("PRY_adm2.shp")

read.csv("coord.csv") -> data
Data <- data.frame(data[,1:4])

Data[Data$species=="B._nn",] -> primera
Data[Data$species=="B._ghn",] -> segunda
Data[Data$species=="B._bolivianus",] -> tercera
Data[Data$species=="B._brevirostris",] -> cuarta
Data[Data$species=="B._diasphanus",] -> quinta
Data[Data$species=="B._osgoodi",] -> sexta
Data[Data$species=="B._pachacuti",] -> septima
Data[Data$species=="B._phoenicoteru",] -> octava
Data[Data$species=="B._pectinatus",] -> novena
Data[Data$species=="B._peruanus",] -> decima
Data[Data$species=="B._thomasi",] -> once
rownames(Data) <- data[,1]
attach(Data)
na.omit(Data) -> Data
alt <- raster("alt.bil")
extent_all <-extent (-85, -50, -30, 5)
crop(alt, extent_all)->alt
tiff(filename = "Mapa.tiff",res = 800, pointsize = 6, width = 3200, height = 3200, units = "px")

#...
#Continues a little bit...plotting...

box()
dev.off()
```

Thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: This is not a reproducible example. Please create a minimal reproducible example. In general a shp file will not a have a background, it will be up to how the plots are created what the background is.

Comment: But when i use `readShapePoly()`, i can plot the .shp and add some color using the the parameter: `col=alpha("darkgreen",0.4)`. I´m asking if there´s other function which i can use with that parameter. Excuseme if i didn´t write before. And thanks for your Answer mmel!

Comment: `bg` defines the background colour.  Your example is full of un reproducible code and very little to do with your actual problem.

Comment: I see...thanks!, i´ll try with your answer!.

Answer (score 1):

In general a shp file will not a have a background, it will be up to how the plots are created what the background colour will be.

Using the example from `?readShapeSpatial`

```
xx <- readShapeSpatial(system.file("shapes/sids.shp", package="maptools")[1],
                   IDvar="FIPSNO", proj4string=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=clrk66"))
```

(1) Set while plotting using `bg`

i.e.

```
 plot(xx, col = 'red', bg = 'blue')
```

[image]

(2) set he plot background as `"transparent"` and  define in the output device

```
tiff(filename = "Mapa.png",bg = 'green')
plot(xx, bg = 'transparent', col = 'white')
dev.off()
# which gives (converting to `png` to allow this to be uploaded to SO)
```

[image]